# How to calculate or track monthly database growth?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Using oracle how can i track database growth monthly? The following  is a query apart of a query i used to stored information using sql server. Is there a way to replicate the same using oracle?

```
SELECT 
  t.NAME AS TableName,
s.Name AS SchemaName,
p.rows AS RowCounts,
SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
(SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB,
CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
sys.tables t
```

Answer (score 1):

below query using DBA_HIST_SEG_STAT and base on awr SNAPSHOTS and their priod gives the database growth per snapshot. you can change it for monthly output.

```
    set serveroutput on     
    execute dbms_output.enable(buffer_size => NULL);**


    Declare
          v_BaselineSize  number(20);
          v_CurrentSize   number(20);
          v_TotalGrowth   number(20);
          v_Space     number(20);
          cursor usageHist is
                  select a.snap_id,
                  SNAP_TIME,
                  sum(TOTAL_SPACE_ALLOCATED_DELTA) over ( order by a.SNAP_ID) ProgSum
              from
                  (select SNAP_ID,
                      sum(SPACE_ALLOCATED_DELTA) TOTAL_SPACE_ALLOCATED_DELTA
                  from DBA_HIST_SEG_STAT
                  group by SNAP_ID
                  having sum(SPACE_ALLOCATED_TOTAL) <> 0
                  order by 1 ) a,
                  (select distinct SNAP_ID,
                      to_char(END_INTERVAL_TIME,'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:Mi') SNAP_TIME
                  from DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT) b
              where a.snap_id=b.snap_id;
      Begin
          select sum(SPACE_ALLOCATED_DELTA) into v_TotalGrowth from DBA_HIST_SEG_STAT;
          select sum(bytes) into v_CurrentSize from dba_segments;
          v_BaselineSize := v_CurrentSize - v_TotalGrowth ;

          dbms_output.put_line('SNAP_TIME           Database Size(MB)');

          for row in usageHist loop
                  v_Space := (v_BaselineSize + row.ProgSum)/(1024*1024);
              dbms_output.put_line(row.SNAP_TIME || '           ' || to_char(v_Space) );
          end loop;
      end;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the SYS.DBA_DATA_FILES table is what you're looking for.

I should add that you may want to use an IDE for this.  Toad has a pretty good monitor for it, as does Spotlight for Oracle.

Even Oracle SQL Developer (The free one) has a monitor tool.
http://nonfunctionaltestingtools.blogspot.com/2012/12/using-sql-developer-to-create-and-view.html
Go to View --> DBA and create a session, then go to Storage -> Tablespaces and the info will show in the main window.

Or go to View --> DA and create a session, then go to Storage -> Datafiles and it will show details as well.

Comment: Thank you. i will look into the readings you have suggested. i am already using sql developer.

Comment: If you are licensed for AWR, then this will already be tracked for you via DBA_HIST_TBSPC_SPACE_USAGE

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to perform this is checking and grouping by the creation_date column from the database files. Look this query:

```
col growth_gb format 999G999D99
col month     format a20

select to_char(creation_time, 'YYYY MM') month, sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 growth_gb
from  v$datafile
where creation_time > SYSDATE - 720
group by to_char(creation_time, 'YYYY MM')
order by 1 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This script is also good, check link:
http://amitpawardba.blogspot.com/2015/10/oracle-script-to-check-database-growth.html